# Show Progress Bar in Async Task in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to show the progress bar in Async task `onPreExecute()`. But I am unable to pass the `context`. Can some one help?

```
public class myClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    Context ctx;
    ProgressDialog d;
    String s;


    public myClass (String S, Context con) {
        this.ctx = con;
        this.s = S;
    }


    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            d = new ProgressDialog(this.ctx);
            d.setMessage("Please wait...");
            d.setIndeterminate(true);
            d.show();
        }
```

Calling from the Main Activity as

```
 new myClass(MainActivity.this);
 myClassObj.execute(s);
```

Comment: you can use getApplicationContext() method for this

Comment: use constructor

Comment: @RahulKhurana where should i use it?

Comment: new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext()); try this

Comment: `new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());` not wirking.

Comment: myClass need two parameter and you are sending only 1 .It should be new myClass(yourString ,MainActivity.this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this, passing into the constructor.

```
public class myClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private String paramOne;
    private int paramTwo;

    public myClass (Activity activity, String paramOne, int paramTwo) {
       dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
       this.paramOne = paramOne; // "Hello"
       this.paramTwo = paramTwo; // 123
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
       dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
       dialog.show();
    }
```

Call it like this.

```
new myClass(YourActivity.this, "Hello!", 123).execute();
```

Comment: `new myClassObj(MainActivity.this).execute();` is not working.

Comment: not working. See my updated question. I also wantt o send parameter in async class. Also show the receiving code in the async class.

Comment: Not working . `new myClass(MainActivity.this);`  , `MainActivity.this` is red. Giving error. `Cannot be applied.`

Comment: Update your question and post your code on how you are calling this asynctask.

Comment: You do realise you're calling it wrongly right? It should be `new myClass(MainActivity.this).execute();`

Comment: Where are the parameter??  in  `new myClass(MainActivity.this).execute();`

Comment: You pass the parameters into the constructor of your asynctask! NOT `.execute()`

Comment: I your code `myClass task = new myClass(YourActivity.this);
task.execute()` How can I pass parameter ?

Comment: I am passing as `new myClass(MainActivity.this,s);` and `myClasObj.execute`. But not working.

Comment: Please review my answer. I updated it to show how you can pass in parameters into your async class.

Comment: But the progress bar is working for infinite times. How to limit it?

Comment: You will have to  call `dismiss()` in `onPostExecute()`. It is working infinitely because of `setIndeterminate` which means the loading time is not measured.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better approach for this, use progress bar in your activity or fragment and as soon as you start your asynctask set the visibility to VISIBLE and when you get result in on postExecute set the visibility gone by using the interface in activity. Something like this

```
/**
     * Listener for listening events happening in background task, whether cancelled or completed
     * with error or success.
     */
    public interface Listener {
        /**
         * Callback invoked when request is completed and response is got with
         * code == {@value java.net.HttpURLConnection#HTTP_OK}.
         */
        void onSuccess(Response response);

        /**
         * Callback invoked when request is cancelled or completed with response
         * code != {@value java.net.HttpURLConnection#HTTP_OK}.
         */
        void onError(Response response);
    }
```

and in your activity

```
   void onSuccess(Response response){
       //Visibility to Gone.
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be two cases of calling AsyncTask,
When calling AsyncTask in same Activity:-

```
public class myClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
ProgressDialog d;
String s;

public myClass (String str) {
    this.s= str;
}
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        d = new ProgressDialog(getApplicatinContext());
        d.setMessage("Please wait...");
        d.setIndeterminate(true);
        d.show();
    }
```

Calling from the Main Activity as

```
myClassObj.execute();
```

If u need to call in separate Activity or in separate file then u need to follow the below code:-

```
public class myClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    Activity act;
    ProgressDialog d;


public myClass (Activity act) {
    this.act = act;
}


@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        d = new ProgressDialog(act.getApplicationContext());
        d.setMessage("Please wait...");
        d.setIndeterminate(true);
        d.show();
    }
```

Calling from the Main Activity as

```
new myClass(MainActivity.this);
myClassObj.execute(s);
```

Comment: See my updated question. I want to send parameter to async classs.